# References between Spring beans when using a NameSpaceHandler

Tags: java, spring, namespaces

I'm trying to use a Spring context namespace to build some existing configuration objects in an application. I have defined a context and pretty much have if working satisfactorily - however, I'd like one bean defined by my namespace to implicitly reference another:

Consider the class named 'Node':

```
public Class Node {
  private String aField;
  private Node nextNode;
  public Node(String aField, Node nextNode) {
  ...
}
```

Now in my Spring context I have something like so:

```
<myns:container>
  <myns:node aField="nodeOne"/>
  <myns:node aField="nodeTwo"/>
</myns:container>
```

Now I'd like `nodeOne.getNextNode() == nodeTwo` to be `true`. So that `nodeOne.getNextNode()` and `nodeTwo` refer to the same bean instance. These are pretty much the relevant parts I have in my `AbstractBeanDefinitionParser`:

```
public AbstractBeanDefinition parseInternal(Element element, ParserContext parserContext) {
  ...
  BeanDefinitionBuilder containerFactory = BeanDefinitionBuilder.rootBeanDefinition(ContainerFactoryBean.class);
  List<BeanDefinition> containerNodes = Lists.newArrayList();
  String previousNodeBeanName;

  // iterate backwards over the 'node' elements
  for (int i = nodeElements.size() - 1; i >= 0; --i) {
    BeanDefinitionBuilder node = BeanDefinitionBuilder.rootBeanDefinition(Node.class);
    node.setScope(BeanDefinition.SCOPE_SINGLETON);

    String nodeField = nodeElements.getAttribute("aField");
    node.addConstructorArgValue(nodeField);

    if (previousNodeBeanName != null) {
      node.addConstructorArgValue(new RuntimeBeanReference(previousNodeBeanName));
    } else {
      node.addConstructorArgValue(null);
    }

    BeanDefinition nodeDefinition = node.getBeanDefinition();
    previousNodeBeanName = "inner-node-" + nodeField;
    parserContext.getRegistry().registerBeanDefinition(previousNodeBeanName, nodeDefinition);

    containerNodes.add(node);
  }
  containerFactory.addPropertyValue("nodes", containerNodes);
}
```

When the application context is created my `Node` instances are created and recognized as singletons. Furthermore, the `nextNode` property is populated with a `Node` instance with the previous nodes configuration - however, it **isn't** the same instance.

If I output a log message in `Node`'s constructor I see two instances created for each node bean definition.

I can think of a few workarounds myself but I'm keen to use the existing model. So can anyone tell me how I can pass these runtime bean references so that I get the correct singleton behaviour for my `Node` instances?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess the problem is that you actually have two instances of each node definition - one as a top level node (via `registerBeanDefinition`), and another inside `nodes` property of `ContainerFactoryBean`. Probably, you should put `RuntimeBeanReference`s to nodes into `ContainerFactoryBean`.

Comment: I guess that I was creating one named instance and one inner bean instance. I.e - two bean definitions and each a singleton.

Answer (score 1):

I'm a little confused by the question.  When you say `nodeOne.getNode() == nodeTwo` do you mean `nodeOne.getNextNode()`?  Does something like the following not work?

```
<bean id="nodeOne" class="org.foo.Node">
    <constructor-arg index="0" value="nodeOne" />
    <constructor-arg index="1" ref="nodeTwo" />
</bean>
<bean id="nodeTwo" class="org.foo.Node">
    <constructor-arg index="0" value="nodeTwo" />
    <constructor-arg index="1"><null/></constructor-arg>
</bean>
```

Is it because you don't want to specify the `nextNode` in Spring and want instead to have the linkage setup in code?

How about something like the following code?  This looks at all of the beans of `Node` type and calls `setNextNode()` on them.  This means you need to expose the setter of course.  You also might want to have your Nodes implement `BeanNameAware` so you don't have to do the `aField`.

```
public class NextBeanSetter implements InitializingBean, ApplicationContextAware {
    private ApplicationContext applicationContext;
    public void afterPropertiesSet() throws Exception {
        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        Map<?, Node> beanMap = applicationContext.getBeansOfType(Node.class);
        Node previousNode = null;
        for (Node node : beanMap.values()) {
            node.setNextNode(previousNode);
            previousNode = node;
        }
    }
    public void setApplicationContext(ApplicationContext applicationContext) {
        this.applicationContext = applicationContext;
    }
}
```

Comment: An interesting approach to the problem. However, I have the feeling that this should be possible from within the BeanDefinitionParser.

Answer (score 0):

Beans are either declared singleton or non-singleton (=prototype). Maybe yours are created non-singleton, so test it with the definition in the bean:

```
<bean ... singleton="true" />;
```

Further information: http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/1.2.9/reference/beans.html#beans-factory-modes

Comment: I set them to be singletons (see code above) - additionally, if I call isSingleton - it returns true.